# How to use dots in Django URL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the following URL patterns for accessing my API's.

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^api_module/api/1.0/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),
]
```

I created the SQL data by posting the following data in Swagger.

```
{
  "description": "My Test",
  "name": "SK.Test"
}
```

But while accessing in swagger by GET by Id method, I gave the id as name `SK.Test` and I am getting api not found error. Like this,

```
" Not Found : /api_module/api/1.0/mytest/SK.Test "
```

But if created like,

```
{
  "description": "My Test",
  "name": "SK_Test"
}
```

I'm able to get the details by below API while running.

```
/api_module/api/1.0/mytest/SK_Test
```

I want to get the details by get by id method using with dots. Hope you understood my question. Can any one clarify my doubt?

Comment: You escape them.

Comment: Sorry Willem I couldn't understand your answer?

Answer (score 6):

The default router specifically excludes dots from the pattern it matches. If you want to include them, you need to define `lookup_value_regex` in your view set.

```
class MyViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    lookup_value_regex = r"[\w.]+"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. My API is working with dot by using this look up value in view set.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, to help future searchers.

Comment: Use `r"[\w.-]+"` if you need username with dots and UUIDs as well.